# Javascript object exists but returns undefined

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest, undefined

I am stumped!
My PHP echos "result~~<File Uploaded OK>~~\n".
"result" gets added as a key to xhrData with a value of "File Uploaded OK".
Using the for-in loop logs the data I expect, but when I try to log xhrData.result, it returns undefined. console.log(JSON.stringify(xhrData)) also logs what I expect. I am so confused! Any help would be appreciated.

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
    if ( 4 == this.readyState && 200 == this.status ) {
        // PHP returns "result~~<File Uploaded OK>~~\n"
        response = xhr.responseText.split(">~~\n");
        var xhrData = {};
        for(j=0;j<response.length-1;j++) {
            splt = response[j].split("~~<");
            key = splt[0];
            data = splt[1];
            xhrData[key] = data;
        }
        for(key in xhrData) {
            console.log("Key: "+key+"\nData: "+xhrData[key]);
           //Key: result
           //Data: File Uploaded OK
        }
        console.log(xhrData.result);      //undefined
        console.log(xhrData['result']);   //undefined
    }
};
```

Comment: You're going to bump your head on this and a million other things with ajax. Unless you're developing your own ajax routine for self-eduction, just use a library like jQuery. http://www.jquery.com

Comment: Try `console.log(xhrData);` to see what properties that object has. Make sure it has a result property.

Comment: @JonathanM, please keep this kind of opiniated advice for yourself. You might be wrong, and you do not answer the question nor help for its resolution.

Comment: @JonathanM — I fail to see how jQuery would help at all with the problem described here.

Comment: Are you sure the value is `result` and not, for instance, prefixed or suffixed with a space?

Comment: console.log(xhrData) returns "object Object". JSON.stringify returns {"result":"File Uploaded Sucessfully.<br />Matrix Uploaded and Saved Successfully."}.

Comment: It probably won't solve the problem, but I'd use an array instead of an object xhrData if your intent is to store data in an array.

Comment: if I run your code in jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/fahpfp9y/) it works fine. I suspect a `responseText` not being what you think it is.

Comment: @Sebas — Nobody has mentioned arrays until you.

Comment: You seem to be reinventing the wheel here, if you want key-value pairs, it would be a lot easier to return json from your php script and parse that.

Comment: @Quentin right, `xhrData[key] = data;` reminds me more of an array value association than a object property definition. I didn't say it was invalid.

Comment: @Sebas — It's the only way to define a value for a property when the name of the property is stored in a variable.

Comment: And what about `console.log("'" + xhr.responseText + "'");`? (To see the potential whitespaces)

Comment: Crazy! Thanks @Quentin. Trying to log the key value does not show white spaces, but alerting the key value shows an unknown character before "result". Not sure where this is coming from, but I will try encoding the PHP response as JSON to see if it gets rid of the character.

Comment: @Sebas, no, I won't.